# T-SQL: how to group rows on a specific column?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        IncreasmentAmount,
        Name, 
        regionid
FROM         Pricing.GroupOfRegions
WHERE   regionid in (6,7)
```

This statement produces this result:

```
12.80 AB 6
13.00 ABC 6
15.00 AC 6
12.80 AB 7
13.00 ABC 7
```

I'd like to add more conditions where `IncreasmentAmount`s are equal. This would result in the rows that have the same IncreasmentAmount:

```
12.80 AB 6
12.80 AB 7
```

How can I modify the query to produce the results I want?

Comment: your output should be 4 rows not two, two for 13.00 and two for 12.80

Answer (score 3):

example

```
create table #bla(IncreasmentAmount decimal(16,2),Name varchar(40),regionid int)
insert #bla values(12.80, 'AB', 6)
insert #bla values(13.00, 'ABC', 6)
insert #bla values(15.00, 'AC', 6)
insert #bla values(12.80, 'AB', 7)
insert #bla values(13.00, 'ABC', 7)
```

here is one way of doing it

```
    --group also by name
select b.* from(
SELECT  IncreasmentAmount, Name
FROM         #bla
where regionid in (6,7)
group by IncreasmentAmount, Name
having count(*) > 1) as a
join #bla b on a.IncreasmentAmount = b.IncreasmentAmount
and a.Name = b.Name
where b.regionid in (6,7)
```

or

```
  -- don not group by name
select b.* from(
SELECT  IncreasmentAmount
FROM         #bla
where regionid in (6,7)
group by IncreasmentAmount
having count(*) > 1) as a
join #bla b on a.IncreasmentAmount = b.IncreasmentAmount
where b.regionid in (6,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IncreasmentAmount, Name, regionid, count(*)
FROM  Pricing.GroupOfRegions 
where regionid in (6,7) 
group by IncreasmentAmount, Name, regionid
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you need to show only rows for which the 1st column equals some other row, then I am afraid you'll have to do a nested query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IncreasmentAmount, Name, regionid
FROM         Pricing.GroupOfRegions

where regionid in (6,7)
and IncreasmentAmount IN (select IncreasmentAmount 
                          from Pricing.GroupOfRegions 
                          group by IncreasmentAmount 
                          having COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Comment: you also need to add where regionid in (6,7) in your nested query otherwise if region 5 and 4 have amount 32 and region 6 has it too it will be returned